# mozilla firefox doesnt delete cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, cookies

i have a button which calls `logout` and when i click it, my cookie `auth` must be deleted. In Google Chrome cookie is successfully deleted, but not in Firefox. This is my code

```
let Cookies = require('cookies');
    let cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
    cookies.set('auth', '', { maxAge: -1 });
    res.redirect('/');
```

what's wrong with me or firefox?

i don't understand why someone dislike, is this stupid question?

Comment: Is Firefox caching your JS file? The easiest way to test this is disable the cache (I think you can do it temporarily in the developer menu). You could also try it in Private Browsing mode, or do a hard reload (ctrl + f5)

Comment: @TomAnderson thanks, it works! But, should my site's users do the same move if they can't logout? If so, how can i solve this problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Ideally this won't be an issue. It is the web browser caching the file, not the server. This means that if you go to production with your fixed code, the first version they receive already works, and will work regardless. There are headers you can configure for the server and also in the html (don't quiz me on that lol, Google for details) which tells the browser how long (days, hours ect) to wait before refreshing the cached copy. Or, you could have some inline js which adds a random string to the end of the url to make the browser think its a new file. Make sense?

Comment: @TomAnderson i got it, thanks greatly! you are cool

Comment: ^ nicest comment all day. My best regards :)